# problem in password validation

Tags: java

I am facing trouble in doing password validation. I am taking the min and max value for the range of password from the java class called applicationconstants and calling that in the servlets. I am using the validation function in another java class and calling that in servlet. Please help me in solving this problem.

**servlet code**

```
int minLength = ApplicationConstants.PASSWORD_MIN_LENGTH;
int maxLength = ApplicationConstants.PASSWORD_MAX_LENGTH;

 if (user.getUserPassword().length() > 0 || user.getUserPassword() !=null) {
          if (Validation.validateStringLengthRange(user.getUserPassword(), minLength, maxLength)) {
             System.out.println("servlet");
              isvalidate = false;
              hashMap.put("password", props.getText("error.password.compare.outofrange"));
              session.setAttribute("errorMessage", hashMap);
           }
  }
```

**Validation.java**

```
 public static boolean validateStringLengthRange(String name, int min, int max) {
        boolean isValid = true;
        int len = name.length();
        if (len > 0) {
            if (len < min || len > max) {
                System.out.println("validation.java");
                isValid = false;
            }
        }
        return isValid;
    }
```

**ApplicationConstants.java**

```
public static final int PASSWORD_MIN_LENGTH = 6;
public static final int PASSWORD_MAX_LENGTH = 18;
```

Comment: Hmmm, a lot of words up there but absolutely no indication of what the problem actually _is._ Seriously, that would help a lot :-)

Comment: If i give password length more than 6 and less than 18 it is not taking but its showing the validation error message which i have given in the code.Its telling validation failed.Its actually taking the values from applicationconstants and also comparing it but my aim is take only 6 to 18 characters for password.Hope you understood now

Comment: Interestingly, @John, it's never _called_ for a zero-length password, due to the servlet code :-)

Comment: @ john pickup I agree to your point. Its not necessary.

Comment: @yopirates - since you've refuted all solutions, can you state your problem please (please see the first comment for clarification)

Answer (score 5):

Blind try, since as paxdiablo said you're not specifying the problem

If the problem is that you get a NullPointerException, please double check this line

```
if (user.getUserPassword().length() > 0 || user.getUserPassword() !=null) {
```

and change it to

```
if (user.getUserPassword() !=null && user.getUserPassword().length() > 0) {
```

That should solve it ;)

Comment: i have a doubt is it taking the encrypted password for validation?

Answer (score 2):

```
Validation.validateStringLengthRange(user.getUserPassword(), minLength, maxLength))
```

returns true if it is valid. So you would want to put an error message if it's not valid:

```
if (!Validation.validateStringLengthRange(user.getUserPassword(), minLength, maxLength)) {
isvalidate = false;
```

Note the `!`.

Comment: i have a doubt is it taking the encrypted password for validation?

Comment: @yopirates - run a test and see if it does?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so `validateStringLengthRange` returns true if the password was validated, but you seem to be invoking your error logic if the result was true - are you missing a "not" operator, i.e. should `Validation.validateStringLengthRange` be `!Validation.validateStringLengthRange`?

Also, you need to do the null check *before* checking the length, and I guess it should be an error even if the input is null, so how about:

```
String password = user.getUserPassword();
if (password == null || password.length() == 0 ||
    !Validation.validateStringLengthRange(password, minLength, maxLength)) {
        System.out.println("servlet");
        isvalidate = false;
        hashMap.put("password", props.getText("error.password.compare.outofrange"));
        session.setAttribute("errorMessage", hashMap);
}
```

Comment: i have a doubt is it taking the encrypted password for validation?